# Interim display in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, return, multiple-return-values

I have something like

(query1..... display query1)

(query1 as base to query 2
display query2)

(query2 as base to query3
display query3)
                                                                                                                       QUERY1 UNION QUERY2 UNION QUERY3

is it possible to have interim display in Neo4j?
I want to see how the graph expands

Answer (score 0):

You can draw on the Neo4j Browser (https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/) as part of Neo4j Desktop (https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-desktop/), where you can execute your first query or part of it, check the graphical or text based result, add the next query part and build it up step by step. Positive side effect: the results are positioned among each other, which helps to compare the results.

---

### Update

There are actually a number of ways to realize multiple queries in one.

**WITH clauses**

> "The WITH clause allows query parts to be chained together, piping the
>   results from one to be used as starting points or criteria in the
>   next." from https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/

**UNION clauses**

> "The UNION clause is used to combine the result of multiple queries."
>    from https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/union/

**MATCH chaining, separated by comma**

```
MATCH
  path1 = (:NodeTypeA)-[:MAPS_TO]->(nodeB:NodeTypeB),
  path2 = (nodeB:NodeTypeB)-[:CONTAINS]->(nodeC:NodeTypeC),
  path3 = (nodeC:NodeTypeC)-[]->(:NodeTypeD),
RETURN
  path1, path2, path3;
```

Comment: In other words, all the queries (and their results) made in a single neo4j browser session are visible in the browser. You just need to scroll down to see earlier queries.

Comment: with one query, can I see multiple results? If I ran a query, I can see one result but I want to see multiple results. If I wrote three paths in one query, I want to see the graph for all the three paths

Comment: I’ve extended my answer by three different ways to realize multiple queries in one.

Comment: @VidhishaKorimerla Can you please describe your concrete requirements? Perhaps you already have a graph at hand or prepared queries (verbal or as Cypher)? I would encourage you to post them here, we can take a look at it and guide you more concretely.

Comment: match                                                                                                               path1=(M:METHOD)-[:HAS_INPUT_DATA]->(i:INPUT_DATA),                                 path2=(M:METHOD)-[:HAS_OUTPUT_DATA]->(O:OUTPUT_DATA),                              path3=(M:METHOD)-[:HAS_BENEFIT]->(B:BENEFIT)                                   RETURN path1, path2, path3. when I ran this it's just one graph. Can I display three graphs one after another in a sequence. I want to start with a single node and show how the graph expands.

Comment: No matter which way you choose (WITH / UNION / MATCH chaining), you will always get *one* result. It is possible that the result consists of two or more graphs, which are not connected to each other, but you will get the result as a whole. A delayed display of one result after the other - lets say for presenting to an auditorium - is not intended. For this case you must fire each query on its own and present the result separately. You can do that via the execute-statement-textbox of the Neo4j Browser and the approach described in answer description (upper part).

Comment: @VidhishaKorimerla Is there a reason why you do not want to perform a 3 separate queries in the neo4j browser? That would produce "three graphs one after another in a sequence".

Comment: Thank you so much for all the responses. I just wanted to know if there is a way. I tried all the ways and I came to know that it can't be done. I am an intern and I have a live demo coming up. I thought it would be neater if I can show the graphs in a sequence with one query but anyway I thank you again for the responses.